# How to display and capture user selection on a country map

Tags: java, google-maps, maps

We would like to display all countries by continent (e.g. asia, europe, south america, africa ...) and capture user selection of a particular country within a continent. What kind of options are available for achieving this? This would be much similar to identifying countries on the map in [freerice](http://www.freerice.com). I am not sure of the available options other than google maps, but not sure if this can be done using google maps api either. Need some direction on this.

EDIT: Ours is a Java EE 5 based application developed using java, seam, richfaces and deployed on a jboss 5.1 container

Comment: This is so very vague, can you give more detail of how you are implementing this?

Comment: added more information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to create a clickable map for users to select a country - like [this Map](http://www.mapisland.com/europe_map.php).

This can be done either using an HTML image map, or Flash. You would need to manually define the clickable hotspots in both cases.

If you only have a few selectable areas (rather then every country on the planet), using Google Maps could be used with custom markers (to blend it with your site style) each with their own click handlers to handle the selection.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with HTML and CSS.  And maybe use JavaScript for your functionality.

Here is an example:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/imap.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only advise on the Java Swing case so here it goes. Your best bet is to first find a vector map of the world with different shapes for each country (or make one yourself). Then you can convert the shapes to java2D shapes, create a zoomable JPanel (easier than it sounds trust me) and simply have your mouse clicks checked against all the country shapes with the contains(Point p) method. (of course you will have to take into account the zoom transformations of the panel but as i said it is far easier than it sounds).

Comment: apologize for not giving the platform initially, I have added more information to the question now (its a jee 5 application built using richfaces)